# What is a latency-sensitive application?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am reading the book "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love. I found that the O(1) Scheduler (it was a task scheduler for Linux) had failures managing latency-sensitive applications. What is a latency-sensitive application?

Comment: I suspect they are referring to real-time applications. Eunuchs variants are notoriously bad for realtime.

Comment: A latency application is one that doesn't work well when there are delays/latency. For example, sending an email is not latency sensitive. It doesn't really matter whether it takes 10 milliseconds or 2 seconds to send that email. But Voice over IP is the classic latency sensitive application. Voice packets are useless if they are delayed more than about 150ms as it effectively breaks down the conversation.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing code. Requests for terminology definitions, recommendations, tutorials, research, tools, libraries, code are off-topic. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A latency-sensitive application is an application which needs to react "fast" on specific events. 
Latency is defined as the time between the occurence of an event and its handling.
Example: a media/streaming player needs to react "fast" to incoming media-pakets (network/file) to transform them and bring them somehow to the audio-output.
If you have high latency in this process you will have drop-outs in your player.
I had the quotes around "fast", because in most cases you want to have a detreministic behaviour, but most people expect it to be "fast".

Comment: *"Example is e.g"* -- That's redundant.  What you wrote reads as "Example is for example..."*.

Answer (score 0):

`Latency` means time delay.  latency-sensitive application would therefore mean that those apps would respond immediately.

Comment: No; "latency sensitive" just means there's a time limit for how long something can take. E.g. pizza delivery is latency sensitive because the pizza will be cold if it takes longer than 15 minutes to be delivered (and "15 minutes" is not "fast" or "immediate").